# Access Denied when trying to download a picture from the aws s3 bucket

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I tried using AWSS3transferutility to download photos from the aws s3 bucket and display them on my imageView in an ios app, however, when it gives me an access denied error. I am sure the bucket is open to the public and I set up cognito, so I have no idea why this is occurring does anyone have an idea?

```
func getPicture() {
        let tranferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()

        tranferUtility.downloadData(fromBucket: bucket, key: self.currentQuestionData!._userId!, expression: expression){ (task, url, data, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            })

        }
    }


//bucket policy
{
    "Id": "Policy1562706569188",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1562706565258",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::schooled-deployments-mobilehub-969166170",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The error message displayed in the console is

> "Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2
>   "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3, Error={
>       Code = AccessDenied;
>       HostId = "GHIlY6U4nxxqKQ/Bn8lf3FWjFZZmVhxn3DDjc8YUZY2gkguT6qdqhS54PL85AL7KaSU0Q9gSckw=";
>       Message = "Access Denied";
>       RequestId = EA34AC42C00AE399;"

Comment: Can you view the photo in a browser?

Comment: 403 is always a permission error, even if bucket is public but if request is coming from an IAM role (assume), the role should have S3 permission.

Comment: @Don yea I can view it in the browser just fine

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket is public"? Can you edit your question to show us the Bucket Policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my bucket policy is empty, but I have not blocked public access. Do I need to have a bucket policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein just updated my bucket policy and edited the question still does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some operations are performed on the **bucket**, while other operations are performed at the **object** level.

Replace this line:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::schooled-deployments-mobilehub-969166170",
```

with this:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::schooled-deployments-mobilehub-969166170",
    "arn:aws:s3:::schooled-deployments-mobilehub-969166170/*"
]
```

That will permit access to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suffered this same error and kept thinking why should I make the bucket public to get away with this error. Then I realized one kind of silly mistake which I did. While I was adding this storage via Amplify CLI ($amplify add storage) there is an option which asks for "Auth users" or "Auth & Guest". After that there are some choices like

1. Create/Update
2. Read
3. Delete

I chose only option 1, create/update assuming that all users who can create will still be able to see. And that was the mistake. I needed to select both Option 1 and 2. Which kind makes sense now.

I had to delete my storage and add back to debug this. Then it started to work for download and upload also. Please do remember the public, protected folder also is important.

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem.